# Prove that $f$ is monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I have one exercise related to category theory and I don't know how to do it.

On the following commutative square, prove that if $g$ is monomorphism, then $f$

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>f>> C \\
@V\alpha_1VV @VV\alpha_2V \\
B @>g>> D
\end{CD}
$$

I've done the following: 
Let $s,t:Z \to A $ two morphism such that $fs=ft$. Then $\alpha_2fs=\alpha_2ft$, as the square is commutative, we have that $g\alpha_1s=g\alpha_1t$. As $g$ is monomorphism, we have that $\alpha_1s=\alpha_1t$. And I don't know how to continue...

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is nowhere near sufficient to show that $f$ is a monomorphism (consider if the category had $0$-morphisms and both $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ were such).

Comment: Wow... I see. Thank you so much :)

Comment: That is not to say that it cannot be "fixed". You just need the right assumptions on $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

Comment: Perhaps it is supposed to be a pullback square?

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong, for example:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z} @>\pi>> \mathbb{Z}_2 \\
@V0VV @VV0V \\
0 @>1_0>> 0
\end{CD}
$$

We have that $1_00=0\pi$, $1_0$ is monomorphism but $\pi$ is not.